# How to find the required values in the multiple document in mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

```
I have multiple documents in the collection then I need to find the particular value inside a single document. Is there any way, we can do this? Thanks for any help.
```

This is the following document that I need to fetch some specific values from the whole collection. Its having four collections and we need to find a single value for a particular document inside the collection.

```
{
"A":{
"A1":"Value A1"
},
"B":{
"B1":"Value B1"
},

"C":{
"C1":"Value C1"
},

"D":{
"D1":"Value D1"
}}

I want to get Value of D1 in the above collection. Is there any way to find it in as single query.
```

Comment: I am a bit confused what are `"A", "B", "C", "D"` keys? Can you please explain the collection?

Comment: yes A, B , C , D are the keys

Comment: this is one document in a collection?

Comment: yes, sorry A, B, C , D are four documents in the collection

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused a little bit, but maybe you want [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). You would do something like this (using the [java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/builders/projections/#inclusion)):

```
findIterable = collection.find(eq("_id", "some id")).projection(include("D.D1"));
```

This way you get only one record matching the query for which only `id` and `D.D1` are returned. You can of course change the query to get more records with only specified fields returned.

If you mean something else, please clarify.

**EDIT**: I can see the answer above, so think about using `exists` operator as well, something like:

```
findIterable = collection.find(exists("D1")).projection(include("D1"));
```

This way you get only records having this field and only this field is returned for them (and their ids).

Comment: thanks..actually i want to get the value of D1 on searching in the whole collection where D1 occurs without checking D.D1 is there any way?. As I have 100 of documents in a single collection and want to get some values (30) like D1 in all 100 documents. In this question i have put an example of four documents.

Comment: So, as far as I understand you have a collection with documents (like the four you mentioned) and some of them can have this "D1" field, is that right? If so, you can use the above "exists" filter (and you can add more "exists" filters to one query).

Comment: According to the docs for this driver it is possible: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/builders/filters/#elements